# OpenVPN configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I want to use OpenVPN on Ubuntu. The following three files are provided:

- client.conf
- tccg-ca.crt
- tccg-ta.key

What are the steps to configure OpenVPN in Ubuntu by using these files. I have installed OpenVPN at `/etc/openvpn`.

In `network-manager` when I choose OpenVPN to create a new connection, it asks for User certifcate, CA certificate, Private Key and Private Key password. I am totally blind for next steps. How I can proceed further?

Comment: What do you have in your `client.conf` file?

Answer (score 3):

Just copy these 3 files into `/etc/openvpn/` folder (remember to use `sudo cp`), then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start client.conf
```

where `client.conf`  is your `.conf` file name.

To stop the current openvpn:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop
```